# Getting a 503 when requesting IAP products from Apple iTunes

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I've set up a test user in iTunes Connect and have signed out of the App Store on my device but when I go to query the in app purchases for my app I'm getting a 503.

Additionally, the site at http://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/ says the service is unavailable (and has been so for nearly 24 hours). Is this normal or does it make IAP integration impossible until the service comes back?

Comment: Whether it's normal or not I can't say, but error 503 is quite clear: The service is not available right now, try again later. You should also be handling that error correctly once your app is in the hands of the user, because it's always possible that some service is unavailable for some time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that its merely a matter of playing the waiting game for either:

1. The IAP product or
2. The test user

to fully register on iTunes Connect.

I made no changes and it's working fine now even though http://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/ still returns a 503.

Comment: That's exactly the meaning of error 503. It means "try again later", so it is no surprise that it starts working when you try again later. It might stop working anytime, like when Apple's server is down.

Comment: I understand but I'd expect http://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/ to return something other than "Service unavaiable" for when the service is back up (ie. a 200, everything OK message).