# 109 Cannot connect to iTunes Store 503

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

All of us a sudden, my in-app purchase functionality has stopped working. I'm still using a sandbox user to make purchases, but this error is happening even before trying to make a purchase--I am not even able to retrieve products (either from device, or from simulator). It was working just a couple hours ago, and there has been no code change. This is the error:

```
▿ Optional<NSError>
  - Some : Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=109 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store, SSErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=503}
```

My code:

```
    func loadBundles() {
            SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo(["bundle1", "bundle2"]) { (result) in
                self.bundles = result.retrievedProducts
            }
    }

public class func retrieveProductsInfo(productIds: Set<String>, completion: (result: RetrieveResults) -> ()) {

    guard let products = sharedInstance.store.allProductsMatching(productIds) else {

        sharedInstance.requestProducts(productIds, completion: completion)
        return
    }
    completion(result: RetrieveResults(retrievedProducts: products, invalidProductIDs: [], error: nil))
}
```

It seems like all of Apple's servers are running fine:
https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

What am I missing?

Comment: From other 503 answers from a few years ago on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139648/error-when-call-in-app-purchase-swift and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655305/getting-a-503-when-requesting-iap-products-from-apple-itunes), it's either "try again later" or put an addTransactionObserver in your viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like http://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/ shows the service is unavailable. What does addTransactionObserver do? Is that just way to detect and handle it when the service is unavailable?

Comment: Yes, it allows you to get just a bit more detail.